# Split dataframe into chunks and multiprocess/thread merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two very large data frames (25 million rows each) and I'd like to merge them both together on a common column. This merge currently takes 25 minutes, but I was looking to speed this up using multiprocessing/threading. How would I do this?

The logic would be:

1. Split `df` into 8 chunks (matching number of cores).
2. Merge each chunk with the full dataframe `ec` using multiprocessing/threading
3. Join all of the merged chunks back together.

In terms of code, I have:

```
def merge():
    pd.merge(df, ec, on = 'FULL ADDRESS', how = 'left')

# Apply to dataframe
def apply_to_df(df_chunks):
    df_chunks['tupled'] = df_chunks.apply(lambda x: merge(), axis=1 )
    return df_chunks
    print('finished chunk')

# Divide dataframe to chunks
prs = 8 # define the number of processes
chunk_size = int((df.shape[0]/prs))
chunks = [df.iloc[df.index[i:i + chunk_size]] for i in range(float(0, df.shape[0], chunk_size))]

# Process dataframes
with ThreadPool(prs) as p:
    result = p.map(apply_to_df, chunks)

# Concat all chunks
df_reconstructed = pd.concat(result)

#But this kicks up a type error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-887d170be4dc> in <module>
     12 prs = 8 # define the number of processes
     13 chunk_size = int((df.shape[0]/prs))
---> 14 chunks = [df.iloc[df.index[i:i + chunk_size]] for i in range(float(0, df.shape[0], chunk_size))]
     15 
     16 # Process dataframes

TypeError: float expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `ProcessPoolExecutor` since what you're doing is cpu bound, not I/O bound. Also, the error is coming since you called the float operator with three arguments, maybe try to take it out? Assuming `apply_to_df` and `merge` don't throw any errors, then everything should work just fine.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking about the Exception?

Comment: Yes, I have tried without float too, but the issue is that the i's in the range are objects. Is there an easier way of coding this up with this logic? 

1. Split df into 8 chunks (matching number of cores).
2. Merge each chunk with the full dataframe ec using multiprocessing/threading
3. Join all of the merged chunks back together.

Comment: `numpy` has a method you can use to split a dataframe called `array_split()`.  Just `dfs = numpy.array_split(df, 8)` then iterate over `dfs`.

Comment: How would iterating look? I can't quite figure out the code

Comment: as long as you are using `apply` your code will be slower than the normal merge, if you still want to try then you can use pandarallel and it'll do this for you automatically

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two pandas dataframe in parallel (multithreading or multiprocessing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785109/how-to-merge-two-pandas-dataframe-in-parallel-multithreading-or-multiprocessing)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a prototype that may answer some of you questions and help you with your specific needs:

`python_version = "3.8"`
`numpy==1.19.1`
`pandas==1.1.0`

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
import multiprocessing
import random
from collections import deque

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def merge_dfs(df1, df2):
    return pd.merge(
        df1, df2, on='Numbers', how='left'
    )


def multiproc(df1, df2):
    cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    procs = deque()
    df1_splits = np.array_split(df1, cpus)
    df2_splits = np.array_split(df2, cpus)

    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=cpus) as executor:
        for df1_slice, df2_slice in zip(df1_splits, df2_splits):
            procs.append(
                executor.submit(merge_dfs, df1_slice, df2_slice)
            )

    return (future.result() for future in cf.as_completed(procs))


def create_random_df():
    return pd.DataFrame({
        'Numbers': [n for n in range(1000)],
        'Random Numbers': [random.randint(1, 9999) for _ in range(1000)],
    })


if __name__ == '__main__':

    df1 = create_random_df()
    df2 = create_random_df()

    results = multiproc(df1, df2)

    df3 = pd.DataFrame()
    for df_slice in results:
        df3 = df3.append(df_slice)
    df3 = df3.sort_values(by='Numbers').reset_index(drop=True).copy()

    print(df3)
```

Output of print:

```
         Numbers  Random Numbers_x  Random Numbers_y
0          0              6537              8771
1          1              5697              1072
2          2              6651              6479
3          3              4100              4178
4          4              1528              5827
..       ...               ...               ...
995      995              6552              3865
996      996              1363              8383
997      997              2641              5734
998      998              9034              2759
999      999              7920              7784
```