# Python Pandas Merge Slow For Large dataset For Finding Common Element in Two Dataframe due to Not Fully Utilized In ALL CPU Cores

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, merge

Python Pandas Merge Slow For Large dataset For Finding Common Element in Two Dataframe due to Not Fully Utilized In ALL CPU Cores. Need Help For Multi-Processing/Multi-threading/Vectorization

**Problem:**
[Issue: Not Fully Utilized In ALL CPU Cores in Python Python Merge.][1]

Most of the time, Only ONE cpu core reaches to 100%.

What I am trying to do: I have two dataframes. I would like to find the common value(s) in two dataframes (>100k rows in dataframes)

The 1st dataframe: **df 1** with >100k+ rows and 3 columns

```
// +--------+--------+--------+
// |  key   | value1 | value2 |
// +--------+--------+--------+
// | zwyL15 | py4wG  |      1 |
// | ooooo  | FcuaV  |      2 |
// | QzK5A  | P9uzN  |      3 |
// | 3ft53  | orAqp  |      4 |
// | epjV   | Pjuc   |      5 |
// | xjJRqs | VgtK   |      6 |
// | pe11M  | pXGD   |      7 |
// +--------+--------+--------+
```

To replicate the dataframe df1 above. The code in python:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"key": ["zwyL15", "ooooo", "QzK5A", "3ft53", "epjV", "xjJRqs", "pe11M"], "value1":["py4wG", "FcuaV", "P9uzN", "orAqp", "Pjuc", "VgtK", "pXGD"], "value2":["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]})
```

The 2nd dataframe: **df 2** with >10k+ rows and 2 columns

| key | value3 |
| --- | --- |
| WF4F | teLZQz |
| fv4 | 2f4 |
| aBiTw | dfgbt |
| 8SL | 244fdfg |
| ooooo | f34t |
| jJRqs6mA | thyy66 |
| Xed7 | qd32 |

To replicate the dataframe df2 above. The code in python:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"key": ["WF4F", "fv4", "aBiTw", "8SL", "ooooo", "jJRqs6mA", "Xed7"], "value3":["teLZQz", "2f4", "dfgbt", "244fdfg", "f34t", "thyy66", "qd32"]})
```

The two dataframes might have more than one or none in common. To find the common in 2 dataframes, my code was:

```
result_df = df1.merge(df2, how = "inner", on = "key")
```

The result I got is as below. It works as I expected but the problem is it takes so long time to process.

```
// +-------+---------+--------+--------+
// |  key  | value1  | value2 | value3 |
// +-------+---------+--------+--------+
// | ooooo | FcuaV   |      2 | f34t   |
// +-------+---------+--------+--------+
```

My main question is: How do I fully utilize all cpu cores or even gpu power to process it faster?

Many Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785109/how-to-merge-two-pandas-dataframe-in-parallel-multithreading-or-multiprocessing) and [this](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) you can use dask